# Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank - Not Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a form that allows a User (agency) to sign up another User (client) that will belong to that User (agency).

To create that User (client) I've created a form that passes all the credentials to a controller action via params.

However, when I try to create a new user with those credentials, I am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in AddClientsController#new

Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank

app/controllers/add_clients_controller.rb:6:in new
```

But I can clearly see email and password being passed.

Here are the params from the request:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"d1beVLphq5B5P51BxeVmSYS42NIgBb6m1mLtiQPc7SI=",
 "add_clients"=>{"name"=>"test 3",
 "email"=>"testform3@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "role"=>"agent_admin"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

add_clients_controller.rb

```
class AddClientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    current_user.clients.create!({:email => params[:email], :name => params[:name], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation]})
    redirect_to dashboards_path
  end


  def secure_params
    params.permit(:email, :name, :password, :role)
  end
end
```

the form in index.html.erb

```
<div class="authform">
  <%= form_for(:add_clients, :url => {:action => 'new'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Add A New Client</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

For insight into clients.create, here is the User model and the relationship model

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name.
  enum role: [:application_admin, :agency_master, :agency_admin, :agent_admin, :client_admin, :agent_user, :client_user]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  serialize :adwords_token
  has_many :client_relationships,  foreign_key: 'client_id'                                                                                      
  has_many :clients, through: :client_relationships                                                                                              
  has_many :agent_relationships, class_name: 'ClientRelationship', foreign_key: 'agency_id'                                                      
  has_many :agencies, through: :agent_relationships  

  #Added params role was self.role
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :agency_master
  end

end
```

client_relationship.rb

```
class ClientRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'client_id'                                                                               
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'agency_id' 
end
```

Comment: the stacktrace tells us that your error is in line 11 but your controller code don't have the new action in that line so please add your entire controller code.  i don't find anything wrong with the new action though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That is the entire controller code. I have no idea why that said `11` instead of `6`.  I think I may have copied the trace from an earlier error in an open window.  It is correct now.

Comment: In which line the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the dump of the parameters show, the hash for the values you're after are nested within "add_clients":

```
"add_clients"=>{
   "name"=>"test 3",
   "email"=>"testform3@gmail.com",
   ...
}
```

So to get the value of, say, email, the code would be `params[:add_clients][:email]` etc.

However I would also checkout the documentation on [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) as well as how to organise [RESTful routing/controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) in Rails as you're breaking a number of established patterns with your code.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you for the additional comments as well, I will look to improve these areas.